# third party slider adding dynamic elements with attributes like 'class'. I am using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a react app (converting a static HTML website to react app).
It has a slider (revolution slider I guess) that adds dynamic elements. Like  etc.

Now react doesn't complain compile time. But on the rendering of the page, it fails for the obvious reason. It should append 'className' instead but I can't modify the source of that library or any third party library for that matter.

What is the best approach to handle this use case?

PS: Apologies in advance. I am naive with React!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Disclamer***

If you are not talking about the Revolution Slider I am under the impression you are, please let me know and I will remove this answer. It appears there is a 3rd party library which was made to expose the very problem you are having when using the `Revolution Slider` in `React.js`.

It does appear to be poorly documented but lets see if we can make sense of it by checking the repo's source code.

**Problem**

How to pass a style to the 3rd party popular library `Revolution Slider`.

**Explanation**

If you are speaking of `Revolution Slider` it appears that NPM has a package for this slider [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rev-slider).

It also appears that it has a prop poorly documented in the source code if I am looking at this correctly. [On this page you can see the code](https://github.com/bodunadebiyi/react-rev-slider/blob/master/src/ReactRevSlider.js).

**Solution**

In that file this `function` at the bottom of the page appears to check the name of the `prop` past in.

```
function fetchAttributes(payload, sk = [], ex = []) {
    const attr = {};
    const skip = ['children'].concat(sk)
    const exceptions = ['class', 'src', 'alt', 'style', 'id'].concat(...ex);
    for (let key in payload) {
        if (skip.includes(key)) {
            continue;
        } else if (key === 'class') {
            attr[key + 'Name'] = payload[key];
        } else if (exceptions.includes(key)) {
            attr[key] = payload[key];
        } else {
            if (key.startsWith('data-')) {
                attr[key] = payload[key];
            } else {
                attr['data-' + key] = payload[key];
            }
        }

    }
    return attr;
}
```

That is important because we can see which `prop` it is checking for. In this case it appears it looks for,

```
['class', 'src', 'alt', 'style', 'id']
```

We can also see an [example of that here](https://github.com/bodunadebiyi/react-rev-slider).

**Example Code**

```
import RevSlider, { Slide, Caption } from 'react-rev-slider';

const config = {
    delay:9000,
    startwidth:1170,
    startheight:500,
    hideThumbs:10,
    fullWidth:"on",
    forceFullWidth:"on"
};

<RevSlider config={config}>
    <Slide
        src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dFnvYtPePRA/maxresdefault.jpg"
        alt="slidebg1"
        data-bgfit="cover"
        data-bgposition="left top"
        data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"
        slideProperties={{
            'data-transition': "fade",
            'data-slotamount': "7",
            'data-masterspeed': "1500"
        }}
    >   
        <Caption
            class="tp-caption skewfromrightshort fadeout"
            data-x="85"
            data-y="224"
            data-speed="500"
            data-start="1200"
            data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
        >
            This is a caption
        </Caption>
    </Slide>
    <Slide
        src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0xe4H666drk/maxresdefault.jpg"
        alt="slidebg1"
        data-bgfit="cover"
        data-bgposition="left top"
        data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"
        slideProperties={{
            'data-transition': "fade",
            'data-slotamount': "7",
            'data-masterspeed': "1500"
        }}
    >   
        <Caption
            class="tp-caption skewfromrightshort fadeout"
            data-x="85"
            data-y="224"
            data-speed="500"
            data-start="1200"
            data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
        >
            This is a caption
        </Caption>
    </Slide>
</RevSlider>
```

But more specifically look at the prop being past in. It appears you can pass a `prop` in called, `slideProperties` which is then past to a function call and checks for any of these,

```
['class', 'src', 'alt', 'style', 'id']
```

So to add a style to `<Slide />` or `<Caption />` it appears you can do so like so,

`<Slide class={style.myClass}/>` or `<Caption id={style.myId} />`

It looks a little confusing to me though. in the example code it shows `slideProperties` and `src` being used as 2 separate `props`. But when I read the source code it looks to me as if the `prop` `slideProperties` is an object that takes the keys, `['class', 'src', 'alt', 'style', 'id']`.

Either way, I think operating with the understanding that we can pass these in one way or another that this can be achieved with little effort.

I think it is safe to assume this will work because of the example code I added above which I found from the `README.md` file on [their github page](https://github.com/bodunadebiyi/react-rev-slider). It shows them using `src="string"` in the same way.

We can see `src` being handled in the `function fetchAttributes()` which seems to pass the `props` to the `Components`. With a little `css` you can write a few styles to pass it into the 2 `Components`. Then easily target the `li` tag and `img` tag with your `css`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up using rev-react-slider directly. Thanks for pointing in the right direction. Quick question: How do we handle such scenarios in general in react where third party libraries append elements/attributes not supported in JSX?

Comment: These are unfortunate problems we all deal with. My team does our best to read through the code in 3rd party libraries before agreeing to use it. If we see problems with the code that would make it hard for us to customize the components we typically avoid using them all together. We have been in some situations on multiple occasions where we had no choice but to fork the repo, make the changes our self and then make a pull request to the repo. Then we have used our forked version of the NPM library till the maintainers merge our pull request.

Comment: Remember that only works with open source projects. So make sure to try your best to pick 3rd party packages wisely. Look through their source code as much as you can. I am glad you got this figured out. If my answer did help you get to the answer of your question, please accept it as the correct answer.